# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: existingData.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to work with `localStorage` but I'm getting the error
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: existingData.push is not a function`

I need help please. This the code:

```
let existingData;
if(existingData === null){
    existingData = []
}
existingData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("weather Info"))
localStorage.setItem("weather Info", JSON.stringify(data2))
existingData.push(data2)
localStorage.setItem("weather Info", JSON.stringify(existingData))
console.log(existingData)
```

I'm not able to see the mistake

Comment: There seems to be a great deal of code missing from your example. Can you please make the code executable and recreate the issue so we can help?

Comment: Hint: What if `getItem("weather Info")` doesn't exist?

Comment: How can you be sure that existingData is an Array always? I think you should initialize as an array since the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing why you set the `weather Info` twice or why you don't instantiate the `existingData` variable as an array right away this would fix it from what I can see in your example

```
// get the data from localStorage and default back to empty array if nothing is set there
const existingData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("weather Info") || "[]");

try {
    // push data2 into the existingData array and set it back into localStorage
    existingData.push(data2);
    localStorage.setItem("weather Info", JSON.stringify(existingData));
} catch (error) {
    // this will fail if the data inside "weather Info" is not an array (but also not falsy)
    console.error(error);
}

// do something with the array that includes both the existingData and data2
console.log(existingData);
```

Comment: will fail with same error OP is getting if `.getItem("weather Info")` doesn't exist or doesn't parse to array

Comment: `localStorage.getItem("weather Info")` will just return `null` if the entry doesn't exist @charlietfl

Comment: Well yeah the code is full of those "errors"... I agree :D

Comment: I fixed the non-string parsing error. This is super simple now... who knows what was intended ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think you have the order mixed up, first you get the item from local storage then assign to an array if it doesn't exist:

```
let existingData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("weather Info"))
if (existingData === null){
    existingData = []
}
localStorage.setItem("weather Info", JSON.stringify(data2))
existingData.push(data2)
localStorage.setItem("weather Info", JSON.stringify(existingData))
console.log(existingData)
```

you probably want to make sure it's an array though by doing:

```
let existingData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("weather Info"))
existingData = Array.isArray(existingData) || [];
// make sure this is array so you can push
```

Comment: That's a better interpretation of the question that I had :) nice, I still don't get why we set the localStorage twice

Comment: @Dominik yeah, not sure what OP is trying to do but this should at least get rid of the error

Comment: Just FYI testing for `null` is not the same as testing for `undefined`...

Comment: true, but it will return `null` if they key doesn't exist. extra handling will be needed to make sure the fetched item actually returns an array though

Comment: @Dominik we have to set the localstorage twice because you know from the begining, we are getting the weather info, we have to set it back into the array. if not, the new member of the array will overwrite the initial member.

Comment: thanks a lot guys, i really appreciate ur contributions, it really helped

Comment: One last thing guys, please how do i get back stuffs on the local storage and view them to the users

Comment: @MattAft I think you should throw if the data from `localStorage` comes back as not an array.

Comment: @MichaelAugust What you said about setting twice doesn't make sense to me. `push` will only add things to the array and not override anything. The two times you set `localStorage` just overrides the value in your storage... It does nothing else

Comment: @Dominik try writing it on your system and see for yourself. I may not be able to explain better here.